# Silverlight control goes black in FF during fullscreen (SL 4, Firefox 3.6, multiple monitors)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, fullscreen, firefox3.6

If I click to make my Silverlight object fullscreen in Firefox 3.6 it works successfully, but then if I select a different window (I'm running two monitors so can do this) then a new window appears in my Windows taskbar titled 'Microsoft Silverlight' which is where my fullscreen Silverlight application now lives. So it's moved out of Firefox.

I can click on that new window to return to my fullscreen application but if instead of returning to that window, I click on Firefox in the taskbar, I see my web application running but with a black void where my Silverlight object was. If I try and right click on the black bit, I don't get the usual Silverlight right-click menu.

If I click on the new 'Microsoft Silverlight' window in the taskbar and then click Escape, it disappears (i.e. it exits fullscreen), and the Silverlight app reappears in Firefox and all is well.

This isn't a problem in IE, but my client requires that it work in Firefox. Seems like some sort of plug-in bug, and it doesn't make a difference whether I'm running with windowless set to true or not.

Any tips? Cheers.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this with Silverlight 4 and FF 3.6.6 on Vista.  As soon as I click on any other window (including the desktop) the silverlight app drops out of Fullscreen.  Have you tested this with IE?  Have you tried a super simple test app that just has a single button to put the app into full screen?

Answer (score 1):

The only time i've seen a black screen (region) being rendered was when something funky was going on with the silverlight app (i think it was crashing or something, but the errors were being swallowed up somehow/somewhere).

I discovered that the black region, in my situation, was the result of the background being set to transparent on the silverlight control side (where it's embedded in the web page).

Hope that helps you in your debugging effort.